# Excel VBA Range Command Click Multiple Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to understand the range function with a VB macro to make reporting easier at work. Plenty of help online about this but it only works for one cell. I want this solution to work for multiple cells stacked in a column.

I want to use a command button.

I'll simplify the scenario. If cell A1 = "1" then B2 should say "Green". If "2" then "Yellow" and if "3" then "Red".

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim TrafficCode As Integer, TrafficSignal As String
TrafficCode = Range("A1").Value

If TrafficCode = 1 Then TrafficSignal = "Green" Else
If TrafficCode = 2 Then TrafficSignal = "Yellow" Else
If TrafficCode = 3 Then TrafficSignal = "Red"

Range("B1").Value = SA3

End Sub
```

This all works FINE for me for the one cell (A1).

But what if I want to do more than one cell? Let's say I've got cells A1:A5 with 1, 3, 2, 3, 2

How do I get them to display Green, Red, Yellow, Red, Yellow in B1:B5 ?

I obviously try to edit the Range("A1:A5") etc but I get an error.

The below doesn't work for me.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim TrafficCode As Integer, TrafficSignal As String
TrafficCode = Range("A1:A5").Value

If TrafficCode = 1 Then TrafficSignal = "Green" Else
If TrafficCode = 2 Then TrafficSignal = "Yellow" Else
If TrafficCode = 3 Then TrafficSignal = "Red"

Range("B1:B5").Value = SA3

End Sub
```

Clearly missing something. I think the logic I'm using is wrong.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
Sub Traffic_Light()

Dim myRange As String
Dim rCell As Range

myRange = "A1:A5"

For Each rCell In Range(myRange).Cells

Select Case rCell.Value

Case Is = 1
    rCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Green"
Case Is = 2
    rCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Amber"
Case Is = 3
    rCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Red"
Case Else

End Select

Next rCell

End Sub
```

It walks down the range, checks the value then puts some text in the column next to the value. It should be enough to get you started.